# convert char to a specific value in c++

Tags: c++, char, int, assign

I need to solve a problem that requires me to compare cards in a 52-card deck by suit and by rank. However, the problem arises when I am faced with comparing cards such as the Queen or the King, as they are noted as "Q" or "K", so I cannot hold them in my card's value, as that is declared as int.

How can I assign the letters such as Q or K integer values so I can assign that numeric value to the card?

Comment: The *character* literal `'Q'` could be converted to an `int` value, and the opposite. Or do you mean you have actual *strings*?

Comment: So don't identify cards that way. Q, K, etc. are for human readers, not necessarily for internal use. Write a function that translates internal values into text representations.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the numeric values for the cards from 2 to 10, and then continue with J = 11, Q = 12, K = 13. Ace will be either one or 14, depending on whether it is below two or above the King.

One way is to use a [`switch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) statement

```
int value;
char card;
switch (card) {
case 'J':
    value = 11;
    break;
case 'Q':
    value = 12;
    break;
case 'K':
    value = 13;
    break;
case 'A':
    value = 14;
    break;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I don't know how I go about doing that. Currently, for 2 through 10, I have

Comment: I meant that I have x[i].value=p[0] - '0'; which works fine. I don't know what to do about letters, though.

Answer (score 0):

Number all the cards in the deck from 0-51.

Have a separate array (or two) that specifies that, for example, card #0 is ace of spades, card #1 is two of spades, and so on, giving the rank and suit of every card in the deck.

Now, compare your cards in any way you wish.